# If two lines intersect using cross product

Tags: java, vector

I am trying to figure out if two lines are intersecting in a planar. I have been trying to use the cross product of vectors but have been getting wrong answers with large numbers. I realized that some of it was down to not having everything as long but even after this change I have still been finding intersections that don't exist. Can anyone notice were I have slipped up. I have been trying to figure out for quite some time.

My code is as followed:

```
 public static boolean intersecting_segments ( Line_Segment A, Line_Segment B)
     {

       float side_one;, side_two ,side_three, side_four ;

         side_one =  cross_product( A, B.p) ;
         side_two =  cross_product( A, B.q) ;
         side_three =  cross_product( B, A.p) ;
         side_four =  cross_product( B, A.q) ;

        return ( side_one >0 && side_two <0)|| ( side_one <0 && side_two >0) &&
        ( side_three >0 && side_four <0)|| ( side_three <0 && side_four >0);
     }


 public static long cross_product ( Line_Segment S, End_point r )
     {

    return (long)(((long)r.x -(long)S.p.x)*((long)S.q.y-(long)S.p.y)) -(((long)r.y- (long)S.p.y)*((long)S.q.x-(long)S.p.x));
     }
```

Comment: You should probably change the field datatype to `long` in `Line_Segment`.

Comment: I have changed the Line_Segment x and y to longs and the side_XX however I still seem to be experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure of this without seeing your `Line_Segment` code, but based on what you've posted here, I'm guessing the `x` and `y` fields are `int`s, which you're casting to `long`s in your `cross_product()` method.

If that's the case, then your casts here aren't doing what you think they are: If, for instance you create a `Line_Segment` called `p` with an `x` value that overflows to 50 (i.e. it is 50 more than the max integer value, which means it gets stored as 50), then `p.x` is 50, and all you do by casting it to `long` is to make it  `50L` - it's not going to "undo" the overflow.

You need to change the types on these variables to `long` so they're stored properly, and lose the casts. (er, you don't technically have to lose the casts, but they're pointless)

Comment: I have changed the Line_Segment x and y to longs and the side_XX and have now moved to the problem where I amn't finding intersections that do exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the side_XX variables long as well, which will likely fix your problem.  If these variables have to have a decimal, use a double instead of a float.

The reason being though the cross_product function returns a long, the variables they are being assigned to (side_one, side_two, etc) are floats.  This will force a conversion from long to float, which would lose precision and be inaccurate with large numbers.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html